# Ambari agent is not exist

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I'm trying to setup the Ambari agent in each node in my cluster and it works fine for almost all my nodes unless one, when I try to retray the Ambari wizard to fix the problem for this one I get this error:

```
==========================
Running setup agent script...
==========================

Command start time 2017-12-01 14:52:13
Server error attempting a GET to /rhsm/ returned status 503
Repository HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21 is listed more than once in the configuration
sed: can't read /etc/ambari-agent/conf/ambari-agent.ini: No such file or 
directory('', None)
```

So obviously this error means therer is no ambari-agent installed in this machine,

so I verified if the agent is installed or not with "yum repolist ambari-agent" it replays that the service is already installed

and when I tried to install "yum install ambari-agent", I could not, also there is No directory called /etc/ambari-agent/

I thought about reinstall the ambari agent for this node but I m not sure if this is going to be the good decision.

what should I do??

Comment: You just posted 15,000,000th question on SO :)

Comment: I m glad My question is the 15,000,000th question, so much fine :O.

Comment: should this question got a gold badge

Comment: I'm afraid there is no badge for this achievement but you have +1 from me ;)

Comment: Yeah because I'm the first persone. I deserve this badge as even :(

Comment: @FIL tnk, first comment for the 15Mth Question

Comment: Remove and then install the agent manually on the cluster.

Comment: @cjackson yes this is what I did and it works fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the agent then reinstalling the agent should resolve the issue. The following commands (run on the node that is failing to register) should achieve that:

```
sudo yum remove ambari-agent
sudo yum install ambari-agent
```

You should then be able to retry the installation in the Ambari UI using the cluster setup wizard.